# Opentok react native cannot switch or open Back Camera

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-camera, opentok

"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.10",
"react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
"opentok-react-native": "^0.21.4",

setting position front works perfectly

```
this.publisherProperties = {
  cameraPosition: 'front',
};
```

But when I write cameraPosition: 'back'

It doesn't connect the call and sometimes gives error publisher timeout and shows black screen.

Have tried almost all the solutions from stackoverflow or github but no luck so far.

Comment: Was able to resolve this by downgrading the opentok-react-native library.

    "opentok-react-native": "^0.20.1",

Comment: Can you try v2.25.2 please? this was released last week.

Comment: Hey, yes tried this also but didn't work for me.